# How to measure time of a statement in scala console?

Tags: regex, scala

I'm using Scala to measure performance of regex engine of java. The regexp below executes in around 3 seconds but yet I'm not able to measure it using System.currentTimeMillis. (the last expression returns 0)

```
scala> val b = System.currentTimeMillis; val v = new Regex("(x+)+y").findAllIn("x"*25); b-System.currentTimeMillis
b: Long = 1330787275629
v: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = empty iterator
res18: Long = 0
```

Do you now why the last returned value is 0, and not the amount of ms that scala spend on executing the regexp?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The unexplained duration comes from the REPL calling `toString` on the iterator returned from `findAllIn`. This in turn calls [`Regex.MatchIterator#hasNext`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/matching/Regex.scala#L512), which triggers the search.

```
scala> def time[A](a: => A) = {
     |   val now = System.nanoTime
     |   val result = a
     |   val micros = (System.nanoTime - now) / 1000
     |   println("%d microseconds".format(micros))
     |   result
     | }
time: [A](a: => A)A

scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> :wrap time
Set wrapper to 'time'

scala> new Regex("(x+)+y").findAllIn("x"*25).toString
3000737 microseconds
res19: String = empty iterator

scala> {new Regex("(x+)+y").findAllIn("x"*25); 0}
582 microseconds
res20: Int = 0
```

Comment: +1 for `:wrap` example, although I'm not sure a simple subtraction is the best way to benchmark small pieces of code in the JVM

Comment: You're right, Google's Caliper is a more comprehensive tool, and it's been nicely wrapped up in a SBT-based benchmarking rig: https://github.com/sirthias/scala-benchmarking-template/network

Comment: Is `:wrap` no longer present in the REPL? In Scala 2.10.2 for Windows, I get `wrap: no such command.  Type :help for help.`

Comment: Yes, `:wrap` was removed: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/cE-z6fxkq0U/EszYr_19qgMJ

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the line of code is wrapped in an object; REPL accesses the member.toString after that object is initialized (in order to display results). The templating mechanism might well have chosen a different order of evaluation; or a custom mechanism could do so.

Answer (score 29):

```
def time[A](f: => A) = {
  val s = System.nanoTime
  val ret = f
  println("time: "+(System.nanoTime-s)/1e6+"ms")
  ret
}
```

Use it with:

```
scala> time { 10*2 }
time: 0.054212ms
res1: Int = 20
```

Comment: While this is a much neater way of testing the time something takes, it doesn't answer this specific question because the problem is actually being caused by the code being evaluated not actually doing what the OP is trying to measure.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite interesting! I added a `println("start")` and `"end"` around the line that creates the regex and ran the code - this prints

```
start 
end
```

then pauses for about three seconds before printing the rest of the output.

So it looks like what happens is the regex is being created but not run until `toString` is called in order to output it to the console. To get the test to work, add a manual `toString` call before calculating the time spent.

```
scala> val b = System.currentTimeMillis; val v = new scala.util.matching.Regex("(x+)+y").findAllIn("x"*25); v.toString; System.currentTimeMillis-b
b: Long = 1330789547209
v: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = empty iterator
res14: Long = 4881
```

Also it should be `System.currentTimeMillis-b` rather than the other way around...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to consider using a mature benchmarking library like [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium).

There are many pitfalls associated with benchmarking in general and on the JVM in particular ([this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html) is a good discussion). It's not trivial to avoid them if you roll your own solution.

Comment: Make sense for real benchmark I've just wanted to check what complexity has the algorithm: 2**n or n**k. for this the code above should be sufficent

Answer (score 2):

Consider also this approach for returning the actual output of the applied method as well as the elapsed time, both in a tuple (Scala 2.10+),

```
implicit class RichElapsed[A](f: => A) {

  def elapsed(): (A, Double) = {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val res = f
    val end = System.nanoTime()

    (res, (end-start)/1e3)
  }

}
```

For any given function `def f(n: Int) = (1 to n) product`,

```
scala> val (res, time) = f(3).elapsed
res: Int = 6
time: Double = 46.4378
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement might include multiple runs. A proper benchmarking library is really important if you're concerned about more than relative speed differences, however.

```
def time[A](a: => A, n:Int) = {
    var times = List[Long]()
        for (_ <- 1 to n) {
        val now = System.nanoTime
        val res = a
        times :::= List(System.nanoTime - now)
    }
    val result = times.sum / n
    println("%d microseconds".format(result / 1000))
    result
}
```